# How to add extra reference to join table migration in Rails 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The following migration throws the error below. What am I doing wrong?

```
class CreateJoinTableProjectsUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    create_join_table :projects, :users do |t|
      # t.index [:project_id, :user_id]
      # t.index [:user_id, :project_id]

      t.references :creator, references: :users, null: false, foreign_key: true
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

The error:

```
== 20230720163543 CreateJoinTableProjectsUsers: migrating =====================
-- create_join_table(:projects, :users)
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "creators" does not exist
/.../db/migrate/20230720163543_create_join_table_projects_users.rb:3:in `change'

Caused by:
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "creators" does not exist
/.../db/migrate/20230720163543_create_join_table_projects_users.rb:3:in `change'

Caused by:
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "creators" does not exist
/.../db/migrate/20230720163543_create_join_table_projects_users.rb:3:in `change'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

It says the relation `creators` does not exist, but I'm trying to create it, so it indeed does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved the issue, I was passing the wrong parameters. Here's the way to do it:

```
class CreateJoinTableProjectsUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    create_join_table :projects, :users do |t|
      # t.index [:project_id, :user_id]
      # t.index [:user_id, :project_id]

      t.references :creator, null: false, foreign_key: { to_table: :users }
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```